# How to check the invalid format error for a tiff file

Tags: c++, c, image, tiff

I am using a program which outputs TIFF file. However when I try to open that tiff file from paint or picture viewer or any other image viewer program, I get the responce that the tiff file has invalid format.

I want to dig deeper and see why I'm getting the invalid format error. How can I check that. Is there any C or C++ code that reads a tiff file and performs error checking for the format. What is the easiest way to check this.

Comment: Use LibTiff library. BTW, it is better to replace your existing code with this library call - both for writing and reading tiff images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`libtiff`](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html) to see about opening up TIFF files and [viewing errors](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html#Errors).